# Switching back to the parent window in chrome using Selenium VBA

Tags: vba, selenium

my code opens 2 child windows. Once I perform my operations on each I need to close the windows and switch back to the Parent window.

There is no option as driver.switchToParentWindow.
There is only driver.switchToPreviousWindow.

Eg: I close the 2nd child window --> then driver.switchToPreviousWindow switches control back to 1st child window but when I close this window and do driver.SwitchToPreviousWindow, it searches for the recently closed 2nd child window whereas I want it to switch control to the parent window.

I have tried looking everywhere for a solution, but I can't seem to find one using Selenium VBA to switch back to Parent window.

Following is my code:

```
 For a = 9 To LastRow
      If Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(a, 3).Text = "Report Name" Then                    
 'Checking if cell has 'Report Name'
          StoreFile = Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(a, 4).Text
          Debug.Print StoreFile

  'Click on Report
   Set myelement = driver.FindElementByLinkText(StoreFile)          'Click on report by name
   Debug.Print myelement.Text
   If myelement Is Nothing Then
       GoTo endTry
   ElseIf StoreFile = "CBD_Yoplait" Then
       StoreFile = "CBD_Yoplait" & ".Category Buyer Dynamic"
       Debug.Print StoreFile
       Set myelement = driver.FindElementByLinkText(StoreFile)
       myelement.Click
   Else
       myelement.Click
   End If

'1st child window opens
 driver.SwitchToNextWindow
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:0:07"))

 'Click on 'Report Home'
  Set myelement = driver.FindElementByXPath("//* 
  [@id=""ribbonToolbarTabsListContainer""]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]")
   If myelement Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox ("no element found")
    Else
      myelement.Click
    End If

    'Click on 'Export'
     Set myelement = driver.FindElementByXPath("//* 
      [@id=""RptHomeMenu_""]/tbody/tr/td/div/div[16]/a/div[2]")
     If myelement Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox ("no element found")
      Else
       myelement.Click
     End If

    'Click on 'Excel with Formatting'
     Set myelement = driver.FindElementByXPath("//* 
    [@id=""RptHomeExportMenu_WEB- 
    INFxmllayoutsblocksHomeExportMenuLayoutxml""]
    /tbody/tr/td/div/div[8]/a/div[2]")
    If myelement Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox ("no element found")
    Else
       myelement.Click
    End If

  'Opend 2nd child window
   driver.SwitchToNextWindow
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:0:05"))

   'Click on 'Export filter details'
   Set myelement = driver.FindElementById("exportFilterDetails")
   If myelement Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox ("no element found")
  Else
      myelement.Click
   End If

  'Click on Export button
   Set myelement = driver.FindElementById("3131")
   If myelement Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox ("no element found")
   Else
       myelement.Click
   End If

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:0:08"))

    FileSpec = StoreFile & ".xls*"
    Debug.Print FileSpec
            FileName = Dir(MyDir & FileSpec)
            Debug.Print FileName
        If FileName <> "" Then
            MostRecentFile = FileName
            MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(MyDir & FileName)
        Do While FileName <> ""
            If FileDateTime(MyDir & FileName) > MostRecentDate Then
                MostRecentFile = FileName
                MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(MyDir & FileName)
            End If
        FileName = Dir
        Loop
        End If

    MyFile = MostRecentFile
    Debug.Print MyFile
    ChDir MyDir
    Set SrcWb = Workbooks.Open(MyDir + MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)                   
   'Saving as xls workbook
    SrcWb.SaveAs DestFolder & MyFile, XlFileFormat.xlExcel8

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:0:04"))

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   SrcWb.Close

   driver.Close
   driver.SwitchToPreviousWindow
   driver.Close
   driver.SwitchToPreviousWindow ( Want to switch back to parent window)
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:0:08"))

endTry:
      End If
   Next a
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Can you reproduce in another browser? I know this is (was?) a known issue at least for Firefox

Comment: I am using Google Chrome, the latest version Version --> 65.0.3325.162

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After closing the *1st child window* to switch control to the *parent window* instead of `driver.SwitchToPreviousWindow` a better solution would be to use either of the methods :

- **SwitchToWindowByName()** :

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Switch focus to the specified window by name.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="name">The name of the window to activate</param>
  /// <param name="timeout">Optional timeout in milliseconds</param>
  /// <param name="raise">Optional - Raise an exception after the timeout when true</param>
  /// <returns>Current web driver</returns>
  public Window SwitchToWindowByName(string name, int timeout = -1, bool raise = true) {
      try {
      return session.windows.SwitchToWindowByName(name, timeout);
      } catch (Errors.NoSuchWindowError) {
      if (raise)
          throw new Errors.NoSuchWindowError(name);
      return null;
      }
  }
  ```
- **SwitchToWindowByTitle()** :

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Switch focus to the specified window by title.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="title">The title of the window to activate</param>
  /// <param name="timeout">Optional timeout in milliseconds</param>
  /// <param name="raise">Optional - Raise an exception after the timeout when true</param>
  /// <returns>Current web driver</returns>
  public Window SwitchToWindowByTitle(string title, int timeout = -1, bool raise = true) {
      try {
      return session.windows.SwitchToWindowByTitle(title, timeout);
      } catch (Errors.NoSuchWindowError) {
      if (raise)
          throw new Errors.NoSuchWindowError(title);
      return null;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB, I took the idea from your solution, it was just  a simple one line change 'driver.SwitchToWindowByTitle("WindowTitle")' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I took the idea from @DebanjanB's solution, it was just a simple one-line change 'driver.SwitchToWindowByTitle("WindowTitle")' and it worked.

Comment: Since his answer led to the resolving of your issue, it would be kosher to upvote and/or mark his response as the answer to your question.